# Extract YouTube Channel Community Feed Data

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, data-science, youtube-data-api

I am trying to collect the community feed data from a channel for analytics.
I couldn't find a way using the YouTube Data API v3. Is there a way to extract such data?

The data I would like to extract is in the community feed. For instance, it's a community feed from [Dr. Bharatendra Rai channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/westlandindia). I would like to collect all his feed.
[image: Dr. Bharatendra Rai community post]

Comment: I want to extract the community polls of specific channel.

Comment: Note that [I updated significantly my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72235812).

Answer (score 3):

One more time [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) doesn't provide a basic feature.

I would suggest you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/e0768177d69464a74eb4a8eb25be91c2d26ed707) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com), indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=community&id=CHANNEL_ID you would get a JSON with the channel community posts (texts, images, videos, polls without answers, likes count, comments count, date etc) you are looking for in `item['community']`.

Note that my API doesn't enable retrieving poll answers as it requires to be connected with a YouTube account. Furthermore currently retrieving comments for a given community post isn't supported too by my API.

Note that [the pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) of my API works as the one of YouTube Data API v3.

Example of result with the YouTube channel id [`UCQxJsAlqmBPAbR_0syDi9mg`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQxJsAlqmBPAbR_0syDi9mg/community):

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UCQxJsAlqmBPAbR_0syDi9mg",
            "community": [
                {
                    "id": "UgkxZ8SQN2CQpX022xUKBJNYCvY3VtGYMrt3",
                    "date": "3 weeks ago",
                    "contentText": [
                        {
                            "text": "Quick question, everyone: Who owns the products that you buy? If the answer is you, shouldn\u2019t you be able to repair what you rightfully own?"
                        }
                    ],
                    "likes": 8,
                    "comments": 1,
                    "videoId": "d4sYQ22Y00k",
                    "image": null,
                    "poll": null,
                    "edited": false
                },
                ...
            ],
            "nextPageToken": "4qmFsgKBARIYVUNReEpzQWxxbUJQQWJSXzBzeURpOW1nGkxFZ2xqYjIxdGRXNXBkSG00QVFDcUF4d0tHRkV3T1ZGbFJ6RktUVVZrUmxNd1VucGpSVzkzVVhjOVBTZ0s4Z1lFQ2dKS0FBJTNEJTNEmgIWYmFja3N0YWdlLWl0ZW0tc2VjdGlvbg=="
        }
    ]
}
```

More precisely you would obtain for a post containing:

- text with a video ([`UgkxZ8SQN2CQpX022xUKBJNYCvY3VtGYMrt3`](https://www.youtube.com/post/UgkxZ8SQN2CQpX022xUKBJNYCvY3VtGYMrt3)): see above example
- text with a GIF ([`UgwAKK9XbGapMEH_rNB4AaABCQ`](https://www.youtube.com/post/UgwAKK9XbGapMEH_rNB4AaABCQ)):

```json
{
    "id": "UgwAKK9XbGapMEH_rNB4AaABCQ",
    "date": "1 year ago",
    "contentText": [
        {
            "text": "Here's to all ten thousand of you \ud83c\udf89\nThis is so much more than a phone \u2013 to Fairphone, to an entire industry, and to our community. It\u2019s a physical expression of everything we believe in and have worked for since we started in 2010. \nWe've got lots of interesting, challenging, exciting content in the works and will do our best to give all of you the video's you're looking for on this channel. \n\nCheers for tuning in! Now let's go add a couple more zero's to that sub count ;)"
        }
    ],
    "likes": 39,
    "comments": 4,
    "videoId": null,
    "image": {
        "thumbnails": [
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/6h9etF2mni8uU6rILsz5K3CGFdzepbPQfivxy0wBwtyheeIXanhMkRvAB4PNnJsQ9VUyXSlNvX_I=s288-c-fcrop64=1,151f0000d51effff-nd-v1",
                "width": 288,
                "height": 288
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/6h9etF2mni8uU6rILsz5K3CGFdzepbPQfivxy0wBwtyheeIXanhMkRvAB4PNnJsQ9VUyXSlNvX_I=s400-c-fcrop64=1,151f0000d51effff-nd-v1",
                "width": 400,
                "height": 400
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/6h9etF2mni8uU6rILsz5K3CGFdzepbPQfivxy0wBwtyheeIXanhMkRvAB4PNnJsQ9VUyXSlNvX_I=s512-c-fcrop64=1,151f0000d51effff-nd-v1",
                "width": 512,
                "height": 512
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/6h9etF2mni8uU6rILsz5K3CGFdzepbPQfivxy0wBwtyheeIXanhMkRvAB4PNnJsQ9VUyXSlNvX_I=s600-c-fcrop64=1,151f0000d51effff-nd-v1",
                "width": 600,
                "height": 600
            }
        ]
    },
    "poll": null,
    "edited": false
}
```

- text with a picture ([`UgxjystGgDuX45mgJLp4AaABCQ`](https://www.youtube.com/post/UgxjystGgDuX45mgJLp4AaABCQ)):

```json
{
    "id": "UgxjystGgDuX45mgJLp4AaABCQ",
    "date": "1 year ago",
    "contentText": [
        {
            "text": "Super exclusive "
        },
        {
            "text": "#SNEAKPEEK",
            "url": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/hashtag\/sneakpeek"
        },
        {
            "text": ":  Here's our co-founder and product lead Miquel Ballester in what used to be our recording studio (we're mid-office-move). Notice the professional cardboard-movingbox-tripod :)\n\nAnyways, Miquel is talking to one of our favorite Youtubers for an upcoming project, that we couldn't be more excited about. \n\nBest guess in the comments wins a personal AMA with Miquel \ud83d\udca1\ud83d\udc47"
        }
    ],
    "likes": 31,
    "comments": 19,
    "videoId": null,
    "image": {
        "thumbnails": [
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/QJeFrnIXTmSqYdH7kr3xGx5S-4DoTFZrvL7XaOlZFnCXk173MviBp7Vaw1SxR_m3n6_ezYqA37W_yg=s288-c-fcrop64=1,00001cdaffffe5d3-nd-v1",
                "width": 288,
                "height": 288
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/QJeFrnIXTmSqYdH7kr3xGx5S-4DoTFZrvL7XaOlZFnCXk173MviBp7Vaw1SxR_m3n6_ezYqA37W_yg=s400-c-fcrop64=1,00001cdaffffe5d3-nd-v1",
                "width": 400,
                "height": 400
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/QJeFrnIXTmSqYdH7kr3xGx5S-4DoTFZrvL7XaOlZFnCXk173MviBp7Vaw1SxR_m3n6_ezYqA37W_yg=s512-c-fcrop64=1,00001cdaffffe5d3-nd-v1",
                "width": 512,
                "height": 512
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/QJeFrnIXTmSqYdH7kr3xGx5S-4DoTFZrvL7XaOlZFnCXk173MviBp7Vaw1SxR_m3n6_ezYqA37W_yg=s640-c-fcrop64=1,00001cdaffffe5d3-nd-v1",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/QJeFrnIXTmSqYdH7kr3xGx5S-4DoTFZrvL7XaOlZFnCXk173MviBp7Vaw1SxR_m3n6_ezYqA37W_yg=s800-c-fcrop64=1,00001cdaffffe5d3-nd-v1",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 800
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/QJeFrnIXTmSqYdH7kr3xGx5S-4DoTFZrvL7XaOlZFnCXk173MviBp7Vaw1SxR_m3n6_ezYqA37W_yg=s1024-c-fcrop64=1,00001cdaffffe5d3-nd-v1",
                "width": 1024,
                "height": 1024
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/QJeFrnIXTmSqYdH7kr3xGx5S-4DoTFZrvL7XaOlZFnCXk173MviBp7Vaw1SxR_m3n6_ezYqA37W_yg=s1600-c-fcrop64=1,00001cdaffffe5d3-nd-v1",
                "width": 1600,
                "height": 1600
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/QJeFrnIXTmSqYdH7kr3xGx5S-4DoTFZrvL7XaOlZFnCXk173MviBp7Vaw1SxR_m3n6_ezYqA37W_yg=s2048-c-fcrop64=1,00001cdaffffe5d3-nd-v1",
                "width": 2048,
                "height": 2048
            },
            {
                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/QJeFrnIXTmSqYdH7kr3xGx5S-4DoTFZrvL7XaOlZFnCXk173MviBp7Vaw1SxR_m3n6_ezYqA37W_yg=s2900-c-fcrop64=1,00001cdaffffe5d3-nd-v1",
                "width": 2900,
                "height": 2900
            }
        ]
    },
    "poll": null,
    "edited": false
}
```

- text with a poll ([`UgwSoAm2bGLaJM44UTZ4AaABCQ`](https://www.youtube.com/post/UgwSoAm2bGLaJM44UTZ4AaABCQ)):

```json
{
    "id": "UgwSoAm2bGLaJM44UTZ4AaABCQ",
    "date": "1 year ago",
    "contentText": [
        {
            "text": "What type of videos should we focus on in 2021?"
        }
    ],
    "likes": 25,
    "comments": 7,
    "videoId": null,
    "image": null,
    "poll": {
        "choices": [
            {
                "text": "Tutorials, how to's, tips & tricks"
            },
            {
                "text": "Behind the scenes \/ making of"
            },
            {
                "text": "Documentary series about our industry"
            },
            {
                "text": "Explanation-Animation"
            },
            {
                "text": "Community content (Ambassadors, changemakers etc.)"
            }
        ],
        "totalVotes": 138
    },
    "edited": false
}
```

- a text mentioning a channel ([`UgkxFeexIJyCyz157nuukfI25v_xqFW4_VUi`](https://www.youtube.com/post/UgkxFeexIJyCyz157nuukfI25v_xqFW4_VUi)):

```json
{
    "id": "UgkxFeexIJyCyz157nuukfI25v_xqFW4_VUi",
    "date": "4 months ago",
    "contentText": [
        {
            "text": "YouTube has a new Creator Liaison, "
        },
        {
            "text": "Rene Ritchie",
            "url": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/channel\/UCLBHPoY3NugnZYURxln3fKQ"
        },
        {
            "text": "! He\u2019s worked in product marketing and tech media, posted his first video in 2008 and, for the last two years, has been a full-time YouTuber growing his own channel. Now, he\u2019s here to advocate for creators inside YouTube, to help YouTube better understand and empathize with creators, and to help creators better understand YouTube and everything it has to offer. If you have Platform-level Creator feedback, reach out to Rene at @YouTubeLiaison on Twitter. If you have questions and individual support issues, reach out to @TeamYouTube on Twitter. Welcome, Rene!!"
        }
    ],
    "likes": 2,
    "comments": 510,
    "videoId": null,
    "image": null,
    "poll": null,
    "edited": false
}
```