# Get Community Tab Data on youtube(Python)

Tags: python, html, json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get data from the Community Tab of a youtube channel, however this does not seem to be supported by the youtube api which I have used so far. I have tried many things including parsing the html but with no luck.

The data I wish to get is:

1. Number of community posts
2. Oldest community post date
3. Newest community post date

Thanks in advance to all who help

Comment: Note that I provided an answer to [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72223744).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant really find a way to see the oldest communiy post date or the number of community posts.With webscraping you can only get the firts 9 community posts. So if the Youtubes API doesnt support a feauture that can get you that its gona be hard to find the oldest and the number of posts. Your scrapper will need to manualy load(youtube only loads the firts 9 and then you have to scroll to load the next 9) all of the community posts of a channel count them and find the oldest one.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. Could you by any chance show me how to do that with a simple snippet?

Comment: I dont have time sorry but i can suggest you to use  selenium because you cant do it with soup.And i will give you this link from another post that i think will help you out <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006940/how-to-load-all-entries-in-an-infinite-scroll-at-once-to-parse-the-html-in-pytho>

Answer (score 1):

To precise [user17252227 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73434463/7123660), you better directly parsing the `ytInitialData` JavaScript variable returned in the HTML to avoid using a slow JavaScript interpreter such as Selenium.
As you understand, you will need to use pagination in a similar way as the YouTube Data API v3. Your best luck is to reverse-engineer the community tab by using your Network developer tool tab of your web browser.

Comment: I have already tried that, but it kept giving me errors when I used the .split because [1] was out of range apparently

Comment: I don't know what `needle` you took for `split` but you may have chosen a wrong one as `curl 'https://www.youtube.com/user/Fairphone/community' | grep 'ytInitialData' | wc -l` returns more than 1.