# How can I get posts in the community tab?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get a list of posts in the community tab.

I tried to use the `commentThreads().list()` method, but without success - when I specify channelId, I get the error: `The video identified by the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId">videoId</a></code> parameter could not be found.` Even using the suggested YouTube options (channelId = "UCAuUUnT6oDeKwE6v1NGQxug"), I get this error. What should I do?

Comment: [I already answered this question it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72235812).

Comment: Can I get the number of votes for each option in the poll? I really need it. Here is only the total number of those who voted

Comment: [The commit adding this feature](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/9a607a3906c584ef0a51a6002f1d93645df4c4b7) is not on production, i.e. https://yt.lemnoslife.com does not have this feature. If you try it on your end, *credentials* to a YouTube account have to be provided, [here](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/9a607a3906c584ef0a51a6002f1d93645df4c4b7#diff-3c54112e6b2ee0c9d4fbfa499947cf687387caff64fd1deaf7e862d94b31acedR61-R62).